What is an Industry Best Practice Approach for Website in order to Allow More than One String to be Typed into the Username Box?
We have an old school website that requires end-users to type in their username and password.
All usernames were procedurally generated from an end-user's first and last name.
In left-to-right order, the username is always...


Last Name
First letter of first name


As a specific example, if an end-user's first and last name is JANE DOE, then their username is DOEJ.

The owner's of the website report that many of the end-users seem to have had difficulty remembering their usernames, and that there have been problems with two or more students having the same username.
As a contrived example, JANE DOE and JANET DOE both would have the username DOEJ, except that JANET could be manually assigned to the username DOEJ2.
For a new website, the school requires that an end-user named JANE DOE be allowed to type in either of the following into the username box on the login page...



Number
All of the New Permissible Entries




1.
S08662431


2.
DOEJ




One way of viewing the problem, is that every end-user is being assigned a new username. However, the system must be backwards compatible with old usernames. For the new school website, students can type in their old username, or type in their their new-username, when prompted for log-in credentials. In this view of the problem, each student account has exactly two usernames. The key-value in a SQL table to represent end-users of the system is a procedurally generated student ID number.

How might we allow two different usernames? Either one of the usernames can be used as login credentials.
It is not the case that two different passwords are allowed (different passwords for different usernames)
It is not the case that two different user accounts exist (one account for each username).
Two different key values determines the uniqueness of a user record (a procedurally generated student ID number S08662431 and the abbreviated first and last name).
When a student types in their username, we do not know ahead of time which of the two usernames they are using (old username or new username).
There must be some way to automatically check what type of username it is (old or new) and then query the data-base for the correct record.

How did you solve the problem of DOEJ for both Jane and Janet? Are you using paired username and password to create uniqueness?

What is the format behind the alphanumeric ID? The format should be easy to remember for the students. Similar to  [last name + first letter of first name].

I feel this is not a UX question, but an implementation one. The UX is clear - have a single input field where the user can input either the new or the old login name. The implementation question is better placed at a programming forum (stackoverflow.com, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, or your favorite programming language forum).

You are designing for just one phase of the data migration and need to think further along when there will be more data with the new standard for usernames than the old ones. Although the old convention was not future proof and less practical, you should plan to replace rather than for the two schemes to continue to co-exist.
So you can provide a temporary field that allows old usernames to be entered and checked against (it is possible that the old username of one student can also match the new username of another), but once there are no students that have been issued with the old username, then you can remove it.
